# Исходный код алгоритма сортировки Timsort на Java или C#

Tags: java, c#, алгоритм

Хотелось бы посмотреть на исходный код алгоритма сортировки Timsort написанный на Java или C#.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48044/discussion-on-question-by-trapping-----timsort-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если интересен код *timsort* (и кучи других сортировок) на Си, то [swenson/sort](https://github.com/swenson/sort) весьма достойное место. В `README` проекта  достаточно подробно описано, как его использовать
(несомненно, там еще представляет интерес  stable (так же как и *timsort*) версия сортировки слиянием с дополнительной памятью всего лишь O(sqrt(N)), называемая *SQRT_SORT*)

Также можете посмотреть [yamsort](https://github.com/avp210159/yamsort) -- еще одну попытку реализации stable сортировки слиянием с небольшой (5-10% от N (*5 лет назад SQRT_SORT еще не было!*)) дополнительной памятью на Си. Реализация в template-стиле -- [yamsort_tmpl.h](https://github.com/avp210159/yamsort/blob/master/yamsort_tmpl.h) (пример использования, например,  [data_yamsort.c](https://github.com/avp210159/yamsort/blob/master/data_yamsort.c)).

В этом же проекте, наряду с кодом *timsort* в template-стиле, можно посмотреть код [timsort](https://github.com/avp210159/yamsort/blob/master/timsort.c)   (в основном взят из `swenson/sort`) с интерфейсом, таким же как у известной libc функции [qsort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort)
(пример использования там же, в [measure.c](https://github.com/avp210159/yamsort/blob/master/measure.c) и [Makefile](https://github.com/avp210159/yamsort/blob/master/Makefile)).

Comment: благодарю за полезные ресурсы))

Answer (score 7):

Например, Java использует TimSort, и его можно посмотреть в [исходниках Java](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/TimSort.java/?v=source).

Код, к сожалению, не помещается в ответ. Учтите, что эта реализация лицензирована под GPL, так что вы действительно можете *только посмотреть* (если вы не пишете GPL-проект сами).

Вот вариант [с документацией и гиперссылками](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/TimSort.java#TimSort.sort(java.lang.Object[]%2Cjava.util.Comparator)).

Comment: @Trapping Теперь можете открывать следующий новый вопрос примерно такого содержания: "Я посмотрел на исходный код алгоритма сортировки Timsort написанный на Java, но у меня остались вопросы. Не мог бы кто-нибудь написать для меня свой код на основе этого кода?":)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow жаль что вы такого мнения обо мне, наверно я не лучшим образом показываю себя задавая такие вопросы. Кстати тот момент который я не понял нашелся в этой документации. Проблема состояла в том что я не понял принцип формирования стека с уже отсортированой частью массива.

Comment: @VladD спасибо за ответ. Очень помог.

Comment: @Trapping: Пожалуйста! Удачи!

Comment: @Trapping, _Проблема состояла в том что я не понял принцип формирования стека с уже отсортированой частью массива._ - именно про это и надо было спрашивать